# How to apply animation on custom class in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, eventtrigger

I created my own class that inherits from FrameworkElement (for Triggers property). I want to apply an animation, which will change Angle property:

```
<MyClass Name="MyName" Angle="30">
    <MyClass.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyName" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="0" To="90" 
                            Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </MyClass.Triggers>
</MyClass>
```

The class itself looks like this:

```
public class MyClass: FrameworkElement
{
    //dependency property
    public const string AnglePropertyName = "Angle";

    public double Angle
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(AngleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(AngleProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(AnglePropertyName, typeof(double), typeof(MyClass), new UIPropertyMetadata(new double()));
}
```

Unfortunately animation doesn't work. If I put EventTrigger inside, let say Button.Triggers, then it works. Did I missed something during writing my class?

Comment: Can you verify to us that the value of Angle never changes? A breakpoint in the property setter is not enough. You need to use the UIPropertyMetadata constructor overload that accepts a PropertyChanged callback as binding/styling/animation accesses the dependency property directly, not the getter/setter pair. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587986%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Gusdor: To be honest, I don't even know how to do it. Should I create new class that ingerits from UIPropertyMetadata class and override it's constructor first?

Comment: There is a good example here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9c641ca3-58a0-4adf-b73f-f1cb4761e883/how-do-i-detect-change-to-any-property-on-a-dependencyobject?forum=wpf

Comment: @Gusdor: Hmm... So I should override OnPropertyChanged method in DependencyObject class. But if I create new class that inherits from this one and has overriden method, where I should use this class? Because my class inherits from FrameworkElement, not DependencyObject...

Comment: There is no `override` required. `FrameworkElement` inherits from `DependencyObject`. You don't need a new class, just a static method to pass into the `UIPropertyMetaData` constructor.

Comment: @Gusdor: Ok, so I am using UIPropertyMetaData inside my class. Now I am passing 'new double()'. So I should use static method DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(e), right? Where can I take event e from? Did I understand you well?

Comment: If you don't read the example, i cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<MyClass Name="MyName" Angle="30">
    <MyClass.Style>
        <Style TargetType="MyClass">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsLoaded">
                    <Setter Property="Angle" Value="90"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MyClass.Style>
</MyClass>
```

Try with this..

Comment: In both cases I have an exception. Inner exception of first code: "Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger." And for second code: "Property can not be null on Trigger."

Comment: Yes, for first and second (and I wrote the content of exception above). Do you have any idea, what could went wrong?

Comment: By Setting Angle as 30 before Load will not be used right.. then what was the use of setting as 30 and changed to 90 on Load. What was your requirement?

Comment: I don't want to change value to 90 on Load but I want to animate some object, so it can rotate (ok, it should be from 0 to 360 but this is not impornt right now, I think)

Comment: What was the Structure of this control, Without a structure how would you know it is rotating?

Comment: This property is then used for rendering cube in SharpDX (DirectX wrapper for C#) so I will see, when it is rotating or not. As I mentioned in my question, I can assign trigger to Button, and when I clicked this animation works. So cube is rotating. Now, instead of embeding code into <Button.Triggers> (which I don't want to use) I am trying to put in in <MyClass.Triggers> but it doesn't work...

Comment: For Button it is working coz, It has a structure to change its angle. But for a `FrameworkElement` it doent has its structure, so you cant use simple with a `FrameworkElement`. You need to inherit from a `Control` and define a structure for that. And then use the second `Style` to work with `Trigger` to change the `Angle`

Comment: No Sankarann. I am just embedding <EventHandler> in <Button.Triggers> but it still refers to my component (changing angle) not to button itself. It works, and my cube while rendering is changing angle. I found solution for not combine it with button trigger or any other element. I just put EventTrigger just below (in XAML) my component. That's all :) Thanks for your contribution! (although still I am wondering why it does not work if I want to embed it between Triggers property of my own component.